# Docker Elixir mix 'command not found'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, elixir, dockerfile

Trying to set up docker with a new Phoenix/Elixir app. I've shared the Dockerfile I'm using below.

When I run `docker-compose up` with this Dockerfile, I get errors that say "mix does not exist".

I'm working from this link. 
https://medium.com/@hex337/running-a-phoenix-1-3-project-with-docker-compose-d82ab55e43cf

Thanks!

```
# Elixir + Phoenix

FROM elixir:1.6.1
FROM node:8.2

# Install debian packages
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes build-essential inotify-tools postgresql-client

# Install Phoenix packages

RUN mix local.hex --force
RUN mix local.rebar --force
RUN mix archive.install --force https://github.com/phoenixframework/archives/raw/master/phx_new.ez


WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 4000
```

Answer (score 2):

You're having multiple `FROM`. And the latest one `FROM node:8.2` is the one being used. Simply remove it.

Otherwise, if you put it there with purpose - you need to explain why.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. That was it. Beginner's mistake. :/

Comment: @Andygimma some times you need another pair of eyes to spot a mistake :-) PS: not mark this as an answer with a checkmark ;-)